# How does {% url 'x' y %} function in Django?

Tags: python, django

In the Django tutorial (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial03/), we are advised not to "hard code" urls in our templates. For example, this snippet:

```
<ul>
{% for question in latest_question_list %}
    <li><a href="/polls/{{ question.id }}/">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

should be replaced by:

```
<ul>
{% for question in latest_question_list %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'detail' question.id %}/">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

However, the tutorial doesn't do a great job of explaining what actually happens here. The first example was clear, `{{ question.id }}` would take the value of the question id and it would be placed in the url. But in the second snippet, we are using the keyword (is it called a keyword?) `url` and also doing something with `'detail'`, which I'm not sure where it comes from, though I suspect it has something to do with this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name = 'detail'),
]
```

So, my question is what is happening in `{% url 'detail' question.id %}`?

Comment: The docs you link refer to it as a "template tag", which you can look up in the syntax reference (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/templates/#tags) and get to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand `namespace` for urls. I am trying to explain.

```
url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/detail/$', views.detail, name = 'detail'),
```

In `urls` you give name to the url, like `name = 'detail'`. So whenever you say `{% url 'detail' %}`. It generates a url which tries to fetch the view associated with name `detail`.

But many a times we don't have fixed urls like `r'^page/detail/view/$'` but we also have some `url_kwarg` or `url variable` which needs to be passed. Here we are passing the value to variable `question_id` in url using `question.id`.

```
{% url 'detail' question.id %}
```

Comment: @Sandi, Did it make you understand the working of urls?? Or should I explain more..

Comment: Thanks a lot. Does this mean that the argument `question.id` in `{% url 'detail' question.id %} takes the place of the named capturing group in the regular expression?

Answer (score 1):

you can use [namespaces](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces-and-included-urlconfs) in your urls:

```
app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/detail/$', views.detail, name = 'detail'),
]
```

then in the `url` template tag (it called a template tag) you will use:

```
<a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">
            <!-- ^^^^^^^-->
```

and i think it looks clear. for more detail you can read description [tag url](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/template/defaulttags.py#L1319)

hope it help.

Comment: This doesn't explain how `url` functions, which frankly is quite hard to understand from the documentation for a django beginner.

Comment: i added link for source of the urls tag, inside it you can find details about it and i hope it help more